# Expressing subject vs target

Tags: grammar

Are these translations correct?

1. "As per the survey conducted **on the students**..."

   > **[学生]{がくせい}たちに[対]{たい}する**[調査]{ちょうさ}によると……

   (students are the topic of the research)
2. "As per the survey conducted **among the students**..."

   > **[学生]{がくせい}たちにおける**[調査]{ちょうさ}によると……

   (students are the target population for the research; the topic could be anything)

What would be the recommended way to state the following?

3. "As per the survey conducted on alcohol among the students..."

   (*alcohol* is the topic while *students* is the target population)

Comment: 学生たちに対し調査によると>>> Grammatically, it should be 学生たちに対する調査によると (対し is adverbial. Use adjectival 対する to modify the noun 調査)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On the students
   The researcher is NOT a student,(for example, the researcher is a teacher, scientist and so on) isn't he?
   In this case, "学生たちに対する調査によると・・・" is natural Japanese translation, you already said .
   In addition, "学生たちに対して行われた調査によると・・・","学生たちを対象にしたアンケートによると"　are natural.
2. Among the students
   The researcher may be that a student, that others.
   In this case, "学生内における調査によると" is natural Japanese. 
   I think that an expression like "学生たちにおける調査によると・・・" is similar to "学生たちに対する調査によると" in Japanese.
   It is because that "Aにおける" infers that the speaker is not A.
3. "As per the survey conducted on alcohol among the students"
   The topic is alcohol. The target is students.(The target is not drinking students.)
   In this case, "アルコールに関する学生内における調査によると・・・" is natural translation.

Comment: For case 3 - will "アルコールに対する学生内における調査によると・・・" be correct?As I understand ,'に対する' would mean 'pertaining to'.